Array Index Out Of Bound Error for Finding an element in an infinite array by Kunal Kushwaha video
My Code
public class InfiniteElement{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10 , 13, 16, 19, 20 ,23, 27, 40, 42, 44};
        int target = 44;
        System.out.print(findPos(arr, target));
    }
    
    static int findPos(int[] arr, int target){
        int start = 0;
        int end = 1;
        while(target > arr[end]){
            //temp will the new start
            int temp = end + 1;
        
            //instead of breaking the box we are multiplying
            //so that the chunk of boxes increase the window
            //it will help us to find the target in particular boxes
            // end = end + (end - start + 1) * 2; 
            // + 1 is because we are using the indices
            end = end + (end - start + 1) * 2;      
           start = temp;
        }
        return binarySearch(arr, target, start, end);
    }
    
    static int binarySearch(int[] arr, int target, int start, int end){
        while(start <= end){
            int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;
            if(arr[mid] == target){
                return mid;
            } else if(arr[mid] > target){
                end = mid - 1;
            } else{
                start = mid + 1;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}

I want anyone to find the error and rectify it. Thank a lot community.
Hey folks, how are you doing. This is from Kunal Kushwaha video for Binary Search Problem Solving 1:28:03 Q5 : Position of an Element in Infinite Sorted Array.
When the array is arr = {1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 13, 16, 19, 20 ,23, 27, 40, 42, 44}, target = 44;
I get error like:  Array index out of bound. If anyone finds the solution, please let me.

I would suggest stepping through your code in a debugger, really slowly, working out what you expect to happen at each step compared with what actually happens.

what is the point of the binary search if you are going to add that findPos method to pretty much invalidate the point of the binary search?

The exception not only should indicate at which line the error is happening, it also should give the involved values (index, array length).... I guess: code is not testing the array length, so sooner or later it will try to access after the end of the array (at least in findPos)

Added a method to validate the end value and check if it is within the array index.
If the end value is out of index:

First, we will decrement the end value and calculate a new end value using the formula end + (end - start + 1) * 2.
If the above step doesn't work, we will reduce the frequency.
As a last resort, we will use the start value as the end value.
Let the findPos function provide us with an incremented start value, which we will then use as the new end value. Repeat this process.

Updated code:
static int getValidEnd(int[] arr,int start, int end) {
  boolean isValid=false;
  int vaildEnd = end;
  int frequency = 2;
  int indexInc = 1;
  
  if(start > end ) {
    return start;
  }
  
  while(isValid==false) {
    vaildEnd = end + (end - start + indexInc) * frequency;
    try{
        int val = arr[vaildEnd];
        isValid = true;
    } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        end--;
        if(end < start) {
            end=start+1;
            frequency = 1;
            indexInc = 0;
        } else if (frequency == 0) {
            return end;
        } else if (end == start) {
            frequency = 0;
            indexInc = 1;
        }
    }
  }  
  return vaildEnd;
}
  

static int findPos(int[] arr, int target){
    int start = 0;
    int end = 1;
    while(target > arr[end]){
        //temp will the new start
        int temp = end + 1;
        end = getValidEnd(arr,start,end);      
       start = temp;
    }
    return binarySearch(arr, target, start, end);
}

